# Get closer annotation to current position Titanium Alloy

Tags: google-maps-api-3, annotations, titanium

Im looking for a native way to get the closer annotation to my current location in a map of titanium.
If theres no native way, how can i do it programmatically?
Appreciate, your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get your Current Location
2. Use: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.BasicGeo (-> Distance calculation helpers)
3. Loop through all your annotations, and store the distances in an array.
4. Sort the distances by smallest
5. The closest annotation is the first one in the array